# Swift CollectionView random image when null

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi i have an issue in my UICollectionView. First i have a list of images coming from server containing url image.

But when the url is null, the cell is showing random images. I want when the url is null, is just displaying no image.

I'm using SDWebImage for showing the image to UIImageView.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listData.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionListViewCell
        if let url = self.listData[indexPath.row]["photo"] as? String {
            let urlPhoto = NSURL(string:url!)
            cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(urlPhoto, placeholderImage:img)
            cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `UICollectionViewCell` will be reused, just set the image to `nil` for the cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionListViewCell
        if let url = self.listData[indexPath.row]["photo"] as? String {
            let urlPhoto = NSURL(string:url!)
            cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(urlPhoto, placeholderImage:img)
            cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
         } else {
            cell.imageView.image = nil
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this method to your cell class :

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.imageView.image = nil
    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```